# AngularJS watch array of objects for data change

Tags: angularjs, watch

I'm implementing a shopping cart and want to store the data in localStorage.
I want to watch the variable `$scope.cart` for change so that I can update the localStorage

The cart variable looks like this:

```
[{'name':'foo', 'id':'bar', 'amount': 1 },...]
```

This is the code for the watch.

```
$scope.updateCart = function(){
    localStorageService.add('cart',JSON.stringify($scope.cart));
    alert('cart updated');
};

$scope.$watch($scope.cart, $scope.updateCart(), true);
```

This is the HTML where the user changes the model.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in cart">
  {{item.name}} <input type="text" ng-model="item.amount">
</li>
```

With the following code, the `updateCart()` method is never triggered. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I check that the `$scope.cart` variable did change, but the update was not triggered.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`$watch` only evaluate string or function parameter in its first argument. Change your `$watch` like this :

```
$scope.$watch('cart.name + cart.id + cart.amount', $scope.updateCart());
```

OR

```
$scope.$watch('cart', $scope.updateCart, true);
```

See [reference API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: Isn't `true` unnecessary in the first example?

Comment: $scope.updateCart will never trigger if you pass it in with parentheses as you would pass the result of the function to the $watch which would be undefined in this case. The correct way is: $scope.$watch('cart', $scope.updateCart, true);

Comment: `cart` is an array of objects, it does not have properties like `amount`

Comment: @SKuijers I guess that was fixed in  this edit: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17419684/3

Comment: @TheRedPea yep it seems fixed.  Thanks to rubensMaruizzo for the edit

Answer (score 29):

It is a common mistake to use a variable as the first parameter to the watch expression.

For `$scope.cart`, you should use the string `cart`:

```
$scope.$watch('cart', function () {...}, true)
```

AngularJs has a new watch method, `$watchCollection`. It is basically the same as `$watch` with the object equality option set to true, to watch for a change in a property or an array item.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('cart', function () {...});
```

Documentation: [$watchCollection](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

Comment: $watchColletion saved me, when pushing / removing items from an array. Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what kind of change the OP wanted, but [as seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29189252/1175496) `$watch(.., .., true)` detects even more changes, namely this type of change: `$scope.cart[0].name= "Foo Bar";`

Answer (score 1):

try to change

```
$scope.$watch($scope.cart, $scope.updateCart(), true);
```

to

```
$scope.$watch('cart', $scope.updateCart(), true);
```

$watch only evaluate string or function parameter in its first argument