# Changing $scope property and watching for changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

OK, I'm 1-day new to AngularJS, so this has to be ultra-basic (I hope not an ignorant one about how AngularJS works - I admit MVC is not really my thing, but anyway...).

**My Code :**

```
var PP = angular.module('PP', []);

PP.controller('documentController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.documents = [
        {
            'filename': 'Untitled-1',
            'content': 'Content-1'
        },
        {
            'filename': 'Untitled-2',
            'content': 'Content-2'
        },
        {
            'filename': 'Untitled-3',
            'content': 'Content-3'
        },
    ];
});
```

So, I have declared a module (`PP`), with a controller (`documentController`) and a property(?) in it (`documents`).

---

**So, I have 2 questions :**

- How (any possible way is welcome) could I programmatically have access to and change the `documents` array? (insert/remove/etc)
- How can I set up an event which fires up when the array has been changed, e.g. an element has been inserted?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417597/angularjs-watch-array-of-objects-for-data-change ?

Comment: @AbdulJabbar Well, yes. I believe this one addresses the issue of *watching* for changes pretty well. What about accessing/changing variables programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Accessing the array

In your controller, you just use:

```
$scope.documents.push({filename: 'Another', content: 'Document'})
```

You can do that in any controller function because the array is a variable shared in the scope. Since it's in the scope, you can also access it in your view like so:

```
<button ng-click="documents.push({filename: 'Another', content: 'Document'})">
  Add document
</button>
```

Usually, I'd define convenience functions for this behavior in the controller to be used in views, but in this simple example, this should do.

### Detecting changes in the array

To watch changes in a collection, you can use `$scope.$watchCollection`:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('documents', function(newDocuments, oldDocuments) {
  // do something when the documents array changes
});
```

For a comparison between `$watch` and `$watchCollection`, see [Scope $watch() vs. $watchCollection() In AngularJS](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm).

Note that watches can be tricky: It's not always trivial to detect changes correctly, in my experience those functions are called way more often than they should.

Depending on your use-case, you might get by without any watches (Angular provides many ways to react on changes without using a single watch), and [you probably shouldn't use $watch in your controllers](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html) anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, my question regarding the first part is a bit different: I'm creating a Cocoa/Objective -> JS/Angular bridge, so I'm looking for a way to programmatically access the controller property from the "outside". Something like `PP.documentController.documents.push(...)`. Is something like that possible, or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, wow. That's a whole different story. With Angular loaded, you can do something like `angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app=theApp]')).scope()` to get to the scope from the outside but I'm not sure if that helps in your case...

Answer (score 1):

You access documents the same way you'd access any other javascript array. Meaning the [usual operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) are available.

This is how you listen for changes:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('documents', function(val){
    // documents have changed!
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how can I refer to the `documents` array of the `documentController` of the `PP` module then?

Comment: What do you mean ? Do you want access to documents from other parts of your application? It sounds to me like you need to read up on the MVC pattern a bit.

Comment: Well, perhaps you have a point here. Or, maybe my decision to try AngularJS for this very project I'm currently working on is quite an overkill... :-)