# What is "=*" in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've come across this way of `isolate binding` specification:

```
scope: {
   property: "=*"
}
```

What does the asterisk mean here? Can someone please provide an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The isolate binding with `=*` is to shallow watch for the change in the collection.

**Let me explain a bit:**

Normally watchCollection variables we use in the scripts like below:

```
$scope.arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'lorem', 'ipsum'];
$scope.arrCount = 4;

$scope.$watchCollection('arr', function(new, old) {
  $scope.arrCount = new.length;
});
```

But what if you want to do object binding in html attribute itself?

```
<my-directive my-attr="arr"><!--$scope.arr-->
```

And, if you do this:

```
scope: {
   myAttr: "=*"
}
```

Now, the directive attributes are assigned as it should shallow watch. And the use of watchCollection is good of use this time.

So, the `=*` is to be used when we need to shallow watch for changes (i.e. $watchCollection instead of $watch) you can use =* or =*attr (=*? or =*?attr if the property is optional) as described in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).

Although, we can use `=` for watchCollection to deeply watch the object or array we can use `=*` for the same. But only difference is that using `=*` method the **collection** becomes **true** and when collection becomes true angularjs use the $watchCollection to remove the watcher and it uses the $watch to remove the watcher when collection is false:

```
if (definition.collection) { //using `=*`
  removeWatch = scope.$watchCollection(attrs[attrName], parentValueWatch);
} else { //using `=`
  removeWatch = scope.$watch($parse(attrs[attrName],
     parentValueWatch), null, parentGet.literal);
}
```

So, when you want to shallow watch for the **[collection](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/collections/)** then you need to use `=*`.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9F68Y/61/)? It seems to be picking up changes in a collection without "=*"

Comment: isolate scope doesn't seem to have `$watchCollection` method, can you modify my example to make it clearer for me please?

Comment: sorry, tried what? I can't call`$watchCollection` on isolate scope, so I can't try what you're suggesting... this is confusing part

Comment: Just tried your fiddle using $watch and third argument as true to deep watch and its working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/9F68Y/62/ but it is also working with just `=`. May be we can only use $watchCollection. Will debug and let you know.

Comment: great, thanks, so basically `=*` tells angular that the expression to watch is a collection, correct?

Comment: Yes. It is for collection.

Comment: I think this should be the first thing to mention in the answer :)

Comment: Yeah. Added it as conclusion in my answer.

Comment: cool, but I think that should be the first thing to mention, since the rest follows from this fact

Answer (score 2):

The asterisk is used to change the default watch behavior.

From [the angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-):

> By default, the $watch method is used for tracking changes, and the equality check is based on object identity. However, if an object literal or an array literal is passed as the binding expression, the equality check is done by value (using the angular.equals function). It's also possible to watch the evaluated value shallowly with $watchCollection: use =* or =*attr (=*? or =*?attr if the attribute is optional).

Comment: yes, I've read that, can you please create a simple example that demonstrates that?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-):

> **=** or **=attr** - sets up a bidirectional binding between a local scope property and an expression passed via the attribute **attr**. '
>
> By default $watch method is used for tracking changes, and the equality check is based on object identity.

In the case of **=*** is used to watch evaluated value shallowly using $watchCollection.

There is difference in evaluation using **$watch** vs **$watchCollection**.

The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535415/angularjs-watch-vs-watchcollection-which-is-better-for-performance) gives down the difference between them.