# $watch not working inside directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that looks like this (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
app.directive('rgReportContainer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      projectIds: '='
    },
    controller: controller
  };

  controller.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function controller($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('projectIds', function(projectIds) {
      console.log(projectIds);
    });
  }
});
```

The value for `projectIds` starts off as `[]`, and so the first thing that's logged is `[]`, as I would expect.

What's confusing is that `projectIds` is populated after a moment by an XHR request, but the value is never picked up.

My template looks something like this:

```
{{ reports.included_project_ids }}
<rg-report-container project-ids="reports.included_project_ids"></rg-report-container>
```

I can see in the template that `reports.included_project_ids` goes from being empty to not-empty. There's a point at which I can plainly see that `reports.included_project_ids` has data, but at that point, my `$scope.$watch` isn't picking up the new value.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: It should get fire, could you please reproduce this problem plnkr/fiddle?

Comment: FYI, it's probably better to use promises than $watch here.

Comment: @Casey you might be right although due to the structure of the legacy code it's not possible in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. It's because in my controller I was populating `reports.included_project_ids` by doing

```
reports.included_project_ids.push(project.id);
```

Apparently `push` does not trigger `$watch`.

Once I switched it to something like the following, it worked.

```
var projectIds = [];
projectIds.push(project.id);
reports.included_project_ids = projectIds;
```

**Edit**: I realized that my problem was due to the fact that `$watch` doesn't "deeply" check for equality/inequality by default. In order for `$watch` to work properly for arrays, you have to pass `true` as the third argument to `$watch`.

Here's the function signature for `$watch` form the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch):

```
$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);
```

So I decided to leave my original `push` code and change my `$watch` to this:

```
$scope.$watch('projectIds', function(projectIds) {
  console.log(projectIds);
}, true);
```

That works.

Comment: I have used $watchCollection when listening for array changes, especially adding/removing items. You can get a brief review of the differences between it  and a deep $watch here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535415/angularjs-watch-vs-watchcollection-which-is-better-for-performance