# Changes-aware list in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, list

I'm doing some work on existing angularjs code, and I have something of that sort: I have a list of objects on the client side, which I transfer via a `put` request to a server side.

The existing code simply takes the list of objects in the `$scope` and puts it in the json as is.

I want to implement a mechanism where only the objects that have been changed since some event would be sent.

I can do that hardcodedly and save another list of objects and clear it when I submit the changes, but I want something cleaner - f.e, a Changes aware list,

Then, I could do something in the sort of `list.changedObjects`.

I couldn't seem to find anything like that from basic research, so I was hoping you guys would know something about it.

Comment: You've described one of the core features of Angular, as well as React, Vue, Ember and a few others.

Comment: If it is a core feature, how do I in fact use it? and thanks for the quick comment @Marty

Comment: Use $watch to track the changes on object if any object value will change it will execute.

Comment: I don't really like Angular and haven't used it much but there's definitely a way to do what you want.

Comment: @AmitSirohiya, as I've noted, I'm not particularly familiar with AngularJS, so a more detailed explanation would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is a use-case of `Observer pattern`. https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS has an lib/example to observe changes in javascript object. Then you can trigger an event in `Angular` to do your job accordingly
http://jsfiddle.net/2zT4C/23/

Answer (score 0):

---

### $watch helps to listen for $scope changes

---

AngularJS can then check the value returned against the value the watch function returned the last time. That way AngularJS can determine if the value has changed.

```
$scope.$watch('list', $scope.sendNewList, true);
```

it will will update innerHtml if new value of object is not equal to old value of object i.e if it has been changed.

For detailed info check this - [$watch()](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html#watch) or [$watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs)

[AngularJS watch array of objects for data change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417597/angularjs-watch-array-of-objects-for-data-change)

Comment: Say I have a list of objects, and I want to be watching all items of that list, how do I do that?

Comment: To watch a list instead of returning "scope.data.myVar" return your list.

Comment: So how will I know which object in the list was changed? I assume that if I watch the list, I get the WHOLE new list in `newValue`

Comment: i am assuming that your list is an array of objects.

Comment: Use $watchCollection instead $watch

Comment: Ohh @dima i never heard about  $watchCollection but after having an overview i think it will solve Giora problem